# Back button affect on elements created dynamically by jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a page that makes extensive use of jQuery to dynamically create elements on the page.

After I post through to the next page and then click the back button, all the dynamically created elements disappear when using Chrome and IE.

However, in Firefox and Safari, the elements remain on the page.

How do I get Chrome and IE to display the same behavior as Firefox and Safari?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can add some code or point to an example page?

Comment: Looks like Firefox and Safari recreate the page exactly as it was left without reparsing the HTML whilst Chrome and IE reparse the HTML (and in effect create a completely new page).

Comment: What I did in the end is actually use an AJAX call from the page to get the items from Session and recreate the items myself using jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple cheat:

Grab the innerHTML of your page and assign it to `window.name`. When the page loads, check to see if your data is in `window.name`. If it is, copy it back into the DOM

Answer (score 1):

What I did in the end is actually use an AJAX call from the page to get the items from Session and recreate the items again myself using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to restore some HTML after returning from a back button press (using Firefox) by setting [window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to store the contents of an element.

Similar to this example:

```
<script>
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("sessionHtml") != null) {
        $('#sessionContent').html(sessionStorage.getItem("sessionHtml"));
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
        $('#sessionContent').html('Data that's restored when you come back');
        sessionStorage.setItem("sessionHtml", $('#sessionContent').html());
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div id="sessionContent"></div>
</body>
```

**Important**: This method can not distinguish between if the user is navigating or refreshing the page. And will actually inhibit the ability for the page to be refreshed with new data once something has been stored in sessionHtml. Which maybe is not such a big deal if you're page is dynamic.

Perhaps someone out there may have a better understanding as to how to implement a good browser-independent approach to determining if the event was a refresh or back navigation?